# Convert arguments of variadic function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

This is probably a newbie question but I thought it might be interesting. Let's say I have this function:

```
template <typename First, typename... T>
int ComputeSomething(const First& f, const T&... t);
```

I would like to write a second function that calls the one above in the general case, but converts the arguments when `First` and `T` are of type `float`, i.e., it calls a `Convert` function on each argument:

```
long Convert(float f);

template <typename First, typename... T>
int MyFun(const First& f, const T&... t) {
  return ComputeSomething(f, t...);
}

// This is what I would like:
int MyFun(const float& f, const float& t...) {
  return ComputeSomething(Convert(f), Convert(t)...);
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just to be clear: when `First = float` but any one of the `T`s is *not* `float`, do you want the non-converting version?

Comment: Good question. I don't think that would ever happen in my case, i.e., `First` and `T` should always be the same.

Comment: Have you tried the syntax you actually posted?  If not, why not?  If so, what went wrong?

Comment: That's not valid syntax.

Comment: @Yakk: You can't have typed parameter pack in C++. It's been proposed, but it isn't part of the standard yet. For now you need a deduced pack plus a variadic SFINAE fold.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta: So you want 1) all types to be the same unconditionally, and 2) branch on whether that type is `float`?

Comment: Giovanni Botta: I think you should simply pack up the parameter list of MyFun into a type list, make a metafunction which returns a bool indicating if all the types are floats, and then provide a template specialization based on that.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta maybe you want to [convert only floats](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64a1a064d9158086) ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki will you make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a transparent `Convert` overload, so that non-floats are bypassed (that is, you can have mixed types of arguments):

```
template <typename First, typename... T>
int ComputeSomething(const First& f, const T&... t);

long Convert(float f);

// Transparent converter
template <typename T>
T&& Convert(T&& t) { return std::forward<T>(t); }

template <typename First, typename... Ts>
int MyFun(const First& f, const Ts&... t)
{
    return ComputeSomething(Convert(f), Convert(t)...);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a41ca34090e732e7)

Comment: I  do not like the 'bool_pack', Daniel Frey's way is more transparent (however, even that might be replaced with a more verbose, but more transparent solution)

Comment: I think the first option is the simplest and it works fine for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper to test if all types are `float`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename... > struct typelist {};

template< typename T, typename... Ts >
using is_all_same = std::is_same< typelist< T, Ts... >,
                                  typelist< Ts..., T > >;

long Convert(float f);

template <typename First, typename... T>
typename std::enable_if< !is_all_same< float, First, T... >::value, int >::type
MyFun(const First& f, const T&... t) {
  return ComputeSomething(f, t...);
}

template <typename First, typename... T>
typename std::enable_if< is_all_same< float, First, T... >::value, int >::type
MyFun(const First& f, const T&... t) {
  return ComputeSomething(Convert(f), Convert(t)...);
}
```

The helper is quite generic and can be used in other contexts as well.

EDIT: I replaced `std::tuple` with `typelist`, although the tuple would never be instantiated in the above context. I was just using it for convenience, but since some people think it is too much overhead, I edited the answer.